# Why am I getting the Output "Could not find or load main class"?

Tags: java, antlr4

i am trying to learn how to use ANTLR, so I tried to run an example from the book , but the the cmd is telling me: "Could not find or load main class Test".
Could someone tell me what I did wrong.
Thanks in advance

```
package antlrs;


import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CharStream inputStream = CharStreams.fromFileName("firstTest.txt");
        ArrayInitLexer lexer = new ArrayInitLexer(inputStream);
        ArrayInitParser parser = new ArrayInitParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        parser.addParseListener(new ArrayInitBaseListener());

        parser.init(); 
    }}
```

Comment: The classes name is actually `antlrs.Test` not `Test`.

Comment: @Stepen C I also tried that, but i get the same Error

Comment: OK, so read the linked Q&A.   And also read up on how that Java classpath works.  (There are links in the linked Q&A.)  I expect that the problem is that you didn't follow the instructions in the book **precisely**.  (If you told me which book / where the instructions are, I could check that they are correct.)

Comment: Hint: this is super basic java. If you dont understand what is going on here, I suggest you postpone ANTLR for a few days. Seriously. Rather start with a HelloWorld. And learn how you get from a java source file to .class files, and how to run that correctly on the command line.

Comment: What I mean is: there is no point in learning how to use a specific Java tool ... when such basics still give you trouble.

Comment: (After HelloWorld, do HelloWorld in a package ...)